# Error that doesn't reference my code - apparently in templates

Tags: python, django

The error log of my django project is showing the following error:

```
Exception while resolving variable 'non_field_errors' in template 'admin/change_list.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 882, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 890, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'non_field_errors'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 896, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'non_field_errors'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [non_field_errors] in 'None'
```

This doesn't appear to be referencing any of my code, and as I don't know where the exception was raised, I have no idea how to go about preventing it. It seems to be referencing something to do with Django's templating language, but I'm not sure what. Does anyone know what would trigger this error?

Comment: Share your forms and views.

Comment: @vishes_shell that's hundreds of lines of code...   Is there something I should be looking for in my forms and views myself that would cause the error?

Comment: What's 'admin/change_list.html' like?

Comment: Yes, custom validation of your forms.

Comment: @Jus I have no idea, it isn't my file.

Comment: @vishes_shell I haven't done any custom validation. Is it possible that this is being raised by a form built-in to Django such as `PasswordChangeForm()`? Would this mabye occur by submitting a POST request containing a form in an un-Django way such as ajax?

Comment: If you use stable versions this couln't be the case since Django is fully tested. I suggest you debug your application. Something wrong with validation